# Row coloring too wide (Pandoc MD -> PDF)

Tags: color, longtable, pandoc

I'd like to have zebra striped table rows in the PDF output converted from Markdown using Pandoc. To create Latex tables Pandoc relies on the packages `booktabs` and `longtable`. Therefore I tried to redefine the `longtable` environment. Here's a MWE (Markdown file content):

```
---
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
  - \definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.95}
  - \let\OldLongtable\longtable
  - \let\OldEndLongtable\endlongtable
  - \renewenvironment{longtable}{\rowcolors{1}{white}{lightgray}\OldLongtable}{\OldEndLongtable}
---

| Right | Left | Default | Center |
|------:|:-----|---------|:------:|
|   12  |  12  |    12   |    12  |
|  123  |  123 |   123   |   123  |
|    1  |    1 |     1   |     1  |

  : Demonstration of pipe table syntax.
```

The problem now is that the **row coloring is wider than the actual table**:

[image]

How can I fix this?

**Edit:**
I've stumbled upon some information concerning this issue. The author of a Pandoc Latex Template called *Eisvogel* [states](https://github.com/Wandmalfarbe/pandoc-latex-template/blob/32f99d52a1477014e15a409cb10db658ed060a8f/eisvogel.tex#L507):

> Unfortunately the colored cells extend beyond the edge of the table because pandoc uses @-expressions (`@{}`) like so:
>
> `\begin{longtable}[]{@{}ll@{}}`
>   `\end{longtable}`

Additionally he links to the [Latex Wikibook section about @-expressions](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#.40-expressions). But to the Latex novice I am this is all as clear as mud...

**Edit 2:**
As requested by [Zarko](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/18189/zarko) here's the same as a complete Latex document (output from Pandoc's Markdown-to-Latex conversion):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{%
\usepackage[]{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url} % url is loaded by hyperref
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
            pdfborder={0 0 0},
            breaklinks=true}
\urlstyle{same}  % don't use monospace font for urls
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs}
% Fix footnotes in tables (requires footnote package)
\IfFileExists{footnote.sty}{\usepackage{footnote}\makesavenoteenv{long table}}{}
\IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
\usepackage{parskip}
}{% else
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
% Redefines (sub)paragraphs to behave more like sections
\ifx\paragraph\undefined\else
\let\oldparagraph\paragraph
\renewcommand{\paragraph}[1]{\oldparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi
\ifx\subparagraph\undefined\else
\let\oldsubparagraph\subparagraph
\renewcommand{\subparagraph}[1]{\oldsubparagraph{#1}\mbox{}}
\fi

% set default figure placement to htbp
\makeatletter
\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatother

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.95}
\let\OldLongtable\longtable
\let\OldEndLongtable\endlongtable
\renewenvironment{longtable}{\rowcolors{1}{white}{lightgray}\OldLongtable}{\OldEndLongtable}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}[]{@{}rllc@{}}
\caption{Demonstration of pipe table syntax.}\tabularnewline
\toprule
Right & Left & Default & Center\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endfirsthead
\toprule
Right & Left & Default & Center\tabularnewline
\midrule
\endhead
12 & 12 & 12 & 12\tabularnewline
123 & 123 & 123 & 123\tabularnewline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1\tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: we can't help you if you not provide complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, which will reproduce your problem. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: @Zarko I've added Latex output from Pandoc, hope that helps :)

Comment: a litle bit :-). see if replacing `\begin{longtable}[]{@{}rllc@{}}` with `\begin{longtable}[]{@{} >{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]r
                        ll
                        >{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]
                    c@{}}` helps. for testing i temporary haven't time :-(

Comment: @ Zarko Thanks for your answer! But it seems there's a `}` missing somewhere. What you've proposed throws the error: 

`unexpected "{"
expecting letter or lf new-line
\end{longtable}
    ^`

Comment: indeed, they are missing :-(. before columns type: `\begin{longtable}[]{@{} >{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}r ll >{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]} c@{}}`. now should work

Comment: Ok, this fixes the too wide row coloring on the left side. On the right, it's still the same...

**Edit:** Another issue is that it adds a gap in the background coloring between the columns _Default_ and _Center_.

Comment: i had problem with copy-pat (misprint) dwarf :-). see answer below. in it all is corrected now :-). sorry for any inconvenience ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

like this:

[image]

i extract from yours code *minimal working example*, where i add code which should solve your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{@{}   >{\columncolor{white}[0pt][\tabcolsep]}r % <---
                        l
                        l
                        >{\columncolor{white}[\tabcolsep][0pt]}c % <---
                  @{}   }
\caption{Demonstration of pipe table syntax.}\\
    \toprule
Right & Left & Default & Center             \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \toprule
Right   & Left  & Default   & Center        \\
    \midrule
    \endhead
\rowcolor{gray!10}
12      & 12    & 12        & 12            \\
123     & 123   & 123       & 123           \\
1       & 1     & 1         & 1             \\
\bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this looks promising! But am I right on the assumption that this solution is tailored to the first one of the zebra colors (`white`) I've specified? It would be awesome if a generic solution could be found that ideally could be incorporated into Pandoc (or it's default [Latex template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/master/default.latex)) :)

Comment: i only demonstrate principle (on one row) how to solve problem of coloring tables when you in specification of columns use on beginning and on the end `@{}`. this you can simply extend coloring each second row as is enabled by `xcolor` package. i newer use `pandoc`, so i haven't any clue, if integration require something special. from your example i can conclude, that you only need to add code lines indicated by `% <---`. lets say, that problem with `\rowcolor{...}` is solved, and left integration this solution to \pandoc` left to new question (if it is not straightforward).

Comment: I appreciate your effort very much, no doubt about that! And I just realized that your solution works with any combination of row colors, not only when the first one is white!

But my problem is that your solution forces me to break my whole document creation process because I can't directly convert from Markdown to PDF but instead have to compile an intermediary Latex file which I have to adjust for every single zebra-striped table before I can finally convert it to PDF. So it's not a complete solution to my original question...

Comment: Addendum: I've opened a corresponding issue on [Pandoc's GitHub page](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/4045) to clarify if your approach could be somehow incorporated into Pandoc :)

Comment: if it can't be incorporated, than the simple solution is : not use `@{}` on beginning and end of column specification :-)

Comment: I see, thanks! I've added that info to the issue report over at GtiHub. I have no clue what the `@{}` are actually there for but I got the feeling they do serve some purpose...

Comment: @SalimB, `@{}` on beginning and on the end remove `\tabcolsep` distance of the cell content from start of the first column and end of the last column.

Comment: @SalimB, any news? is answer helpful to you (so much that you can accept it)?

Comment: @ Zarko Yes and no. Your answer is helpful, no doubt, therefore I accepted it. But my original problem is still not solved, i.e. I can't produce zebra colored tables with correct coloring width _directly out of Pandoc_. Since the issue [is known to the Pandoc devs](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3929), I hope there will be a solution eventually...

Answer (score 2):

As of today this is still an issue and @Zarko 's answer cannot be solved through a pandoc filter because it is a writer issue. The script below is a (crude) solution to fix the table colors that can be integrated into a pipeline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
fix-table-color-bleed.py: take a file as argument or input from stdin,
remove @{} from table headers and print the result on stdout 
"""

import sys
from re import sub

def fix_table_color_bleed(infile):

   """
   Remove @{} from latex table entries and print on stdout
   """

   fixedfile = sub("(\\\\begin\{longtable\}\[\]\{)\@\{\}(.*?)\@\{\}",
        "\\1\\2", infile)
   print(fixedfile)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  if len(sys.argv) > 1:
     infile = open(sys.argv[1])
     filecontens = infile.read()
  else:
     filecontens = sys.stdin.read()

fix_table_color_bleed(filecontens)
```

The `(\\\\begin\{longtable\}\[\]\{)\@\{\}(.*?)\@\{\}` part is the regex pattern to capture and remove the @{} sequence. You can use this script by supplying a tex file as argument. To use it in a pipeline you can use for example:

```
pandoc -s --from markdown --to latex <inputfile>.md | fix-table-color-bleed.py <outputfile>.tex
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: thank you :) I'm 4 years late to the party but I hope my answer might help someone in the future